# GPS accuracy of Android Emulator

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, android-emulator

I am developing a website which used W3C GeoLocation API to obtain users' position. I try to run the website in Android Emulator and use DDMS / geo fix to send the coordinate to the device. However the coordinate received is inaccurate. For example, (22.377127, 114.095535) will become (22.370335, 114.08523353). I try to run some Android GPS example from Internet, and the results is just the same. I can certainly say that this is not my program bug. From my observation, it seems like some rounding problem. Can anybody help? Thanks.

My Environment:
Windows 7 Professional 64bit
Android 2.2 with Google API (API level 8)

Comment: If an answer helps you solve your problem, please accept it as the solution. It helps SO by building a good set of answered questions and helps your fellow members by rewarding them for answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the longitude and latitude in 2 doubles... !

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by 2 doubles? I just retrieved from W3C GeoLocation API and print the coordinate to screen.

Answer (score 0):

I notice the same problem. I send lon, lat -83.0000, 40.000 via DDMS and the emulator app receives and -83.013833, 40.006666.